# "This declaration has no storage class or type specifier in C++"

Tags: c++

I have problem with my own class and operator =. When I try to attribute to one object of class Cow another one of the same class outside of some function I get an information "This declaration has no storage class or type specifier in C++". What's the problem? I'm sorry for my english.

```
    #include "Header.h"

Cow cow5;
Cow cow6;
cow5 = cow6;

int main()
{

    Cow cow1;
    Cow cow2("cowa22", "hobby", 8);
    Cow cow3 = cow2;
    Cow cow4;
    cow2.operator=(cow3);
}
```

---

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Cow::Cow()
{
    strcpy_s(name, sizeof(char)*20, "unnamed");
    hobby = nullptr;
    weight = 0;
}

Cow::Cow(const char * nm, const char * ho, double wt)
{
    strcpy_s(name, sizeof(char) * 20, nm);
    hobby = new char[strlen(ho) + 1];
    strcpy_s(hobby, sizeof(char)*(strlen(ho)+1), ho);
    weight = wt;
}

Cow::Cow(const Cow & c)
{
    strcpy_s(name, sizeof(char) * 20, c.name);
    hobby = new char[strlen(c.hobby) + 1];
    strcpy_s(hobby, sizeof(char)*(strlen(c.hobby) + 1), c.hobby);
    weight = c.weight;
}

Cow::~Cow()
{
    delete[] hobby;
}

Cow & Cow::operator=(const Cow & c)
{
    if (&c == this)
        return *this;
    delete[] hobby;
    strcpy_s(name, sizeof(char) * 20, c.name);
    hobby = new char[strlen(c.hobby) + 1];
    strcpy_s(hobby, sizeof(char)*(strlen(c.hobby) + 1), c.hobby);
    weight = c.weight;

    return *this;
}

void Cow::ShowCow() const
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl
        << "Hobby: " << hobby << std::endl 
        << "Weight: " << weight << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: You pasted the .cpp twice instead of the .h and .cpp

Comment: Just a stylistic comment. Don't use char arrays in C++, which your use of `strcpy_s` indicates, use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 9):

In C++, code can only appear inside function bodies or in variable initialisers. This:

```
cow5 = cow6;
```

is inside neither, so it's an error. You cannot have code "floating" outside of a function. Put it inside `main`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run code outside `main()`
You can only define variables, that's why:

```
Cow cow4
```

Works